# Flask - Can't override default subdomain for blueprints needing a different subdomain

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, blueprint

I have a Flask project/app and want it to be served mainly from `app.example.com`. I also have a single blueprint inside this app which should only be served from `api.example.com`.

Now, if I set `app` as the default subdomain, I'm unable to override this default in other blueprints which should be served from a different subdomain (e.g. `api`). In fact, any blueprints created with a different subdomain will 404.

In other words, the code below doesn't work (`api.example.com/test2` will 404):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
app.url_map.default_subdomain = 'app' # set default subdomain, intending to override it below for `api.*`

appbp = Blueprint('app', 'app')
apibp = Blueprint('api', 'api') 


@appbp.route('/test1')
def app_hello():
    # this works (app.example.com/test1)
    return 'appbp.app_hello'


@apibp.route('/test2')
def api_hello():
    # this will 404 (api.example.com/test2)
    return 'apibp.api_hello'


app.register_blueprint(appbp) # this works, serves from `app.example.com`
app.register_blueprint(apibp, subdomain='api') # doesn't work, `api.example.com/test2` will 404, so will `app.example.com/test2` (tried just in case it was using the default subdomain instead)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888, debug=True)
```

However, if I don't set a default subdomain and *instead* set a subdomain each time I register a blueprint, it magically works for both `app` and `api`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
# app.url_map.default_subdomain = 'app' # now try without a default

appbp = Blueprint('app', 'app') 
apibp = Blueprint('api', 'api')


@appbp.route('/test1')
def app_hello():
    # this works (app.example.com/test1)
    return 'appbp.app_hello'


@apibp.route('/test2')
def api_hello():
    # this works (api.example.com/test2)
    return 'apibp.api_hello'


app.register_blueprint(appbp, subdomain='app') # works, explicitly set subdomain on each blueprint
app.register_blueprint(apibp, subdomain='api') # works, explicitly set subdomain on each blueprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888, debug=True)
```

In both examples, it appears the blueprints are registered with the correct subdomain:

```
 <Rule 'app|/test1' (OPTIONS, GET, HEAD) -> app.app_hello>
 <Rule 'api|/test2' (OPTIONS, GET, HEAD) -> api.api_hello>
```

But, clearly, there's a difference between setting `app.url_map.default_subdomain` intending to override it later and just explicitly setting subdomains manually.

Any idea what's going on here?

**Bonus points**: which of these is the preferred way to set a subdomain? I've seen it done both ways.

```
app.register_blueprint(apibp, subdomain='api')
```

vs.

```
apibp = Blueprint('api', 'api', subdomain='api')
app.register_blueprint(apibp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's missing is the [`subdomain_matching` option for `Flask()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask):

> **subdomain_matching** – consider the subdomain relative to `SERVER_NAME` when matching routes. Defaults to False.

Since `app` is a relative name, you need to set this to `True`:

```
app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
```

This used to be done implicitly, but as of Flask 1.0 it's an explicit switch. The change was made because different people had different expectations of what setting `SERVER_NAME` means, see [Flask issue #998](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/998).

As for where you set the `subdomain` option, that's your choice. If you are reusing blueprints in different contexts, then it makes more sense to set the subdomain option in the `app.register_blueprint()` call, while setting it in the `Blueprint()` instance call may make it more self-documenting if you are creating that blueprint object closer to your routes for and so want to make it clearer to someone working on that code that they are affecting a specific subdomain only.